# Hover and transform on div without moving other divs

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations, css-transforms

I am trying to enlarge and show some extra info on mouse hover on div. 
I am using bootstrap grid, the div lying below the mouse-houvering div is locating.

My code is here:

```css
#each_p .product-section {
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      overflow:hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    #each_p .product-section:hover {
      border: 1px solid #717070;
      background-color: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .275);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transform: scale(1.1);
      overflow: visible;
    }
    #each_p .product-section:hover .details {
      transform: translateY(0%);
      display:block;
      z-index:100;
    }
    #each_p .product-section img {
      width: 250px;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #each_p .product-section .details {
      display: none;
      transition: transform .2s linear, opacity .2s ease-in-out;
      transform: translateY(-100%);
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      z-index:0;
      margin: 2px;
    }
    #each_p h4 {
      margin-top: 50px;
      font-size: 30px !important;
    }
    #each_p h5{
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="each_p">
        <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="product-section">
    <img class="img-reposnive" src="../img/product/tv_cabinet/1.png">
    <h5> Cabinet_1 </h5>
    <div class="details">
     <p> PRICE : 19000 Yen </p>
     <p> Size : 162 X 72 X 80 cm </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="product-section">
    <img class="img-reposnive" src="../img/product/tv_cabinet/1.png">
    <h5> Cabinet_2 </h5>
    <div class="details">
     <p> PRICE : 19000 Yen </p>
     <p> Size : 162 X 72 X 80 cm </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="product-section">
    <img class="img-reposnive" src="../img/product/tv_cabinet/1.png">
    <h5> Cabinet_3 </h5>
    <div class="details">
     <p> PRICE : 19000 Yen </p>
     <p> Size : 162 X 72 X 80 cm </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="product-section">
    <img class="img-reposnive" src="../img/product/tv_cabinet/1.png">
    <h5> Cabinet_4 </h5>
    <div class="details">
     <p> PRICE : 19000 Yen </p>
     <p> Size : 162 X 72 X 80 cm </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="product-section">
    <img class="img-reposnive" src="../img/product/tv_cabinet/1.png">
    <h5> Cabinet_5 </h5>
    <div class="details">
     <p> PRICE : 19000 Yen </p>
     <p> Size : 162 X 72 X 80 cm </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need the divs to be at its place and the extra text to be displayed on top of it on mouse hover.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you show any example for the same that you want please...?

Comment: http://www.ikea.com/jp/en/catalog/categories/departments/bedroom/16284/

Comment: the above is an example of what i want to create. just check by hovering on the image

Answer (score -1):

```css
#each_p .product-section {
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      overflow:hidden;
      position: relative;
      transform: scale(1);
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    #each_p .product-section:hover {
      border: 1px solid #717070;
      background-color: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .275);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    #each_p .product-section:hover .details {
      transform: translateY(0%);
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      z-index:100;
    }
    #each_p .product-section img {
      width: 250px;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #each_p .product-section .details {
      transition: transform .2s linear, opacity .2s ease-in-out;
      transform: translateY(-100%);
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      z-index:0;
      margin: 2px;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    #each_p h4 {
      margin-top: 50px;
      font-size: 30px !important;
    }
    #each_p h5{
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="each_p">
        <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="product-section">
    <img class="img-reposnive" src="../img/product/tv_cabinet/1.png">
    <h5> Cabinet_1 </h5>
    <div class="details">
     <p> PRICE : 19000 Yen </p>
     <p> Size : 162 X 72 X 80 cm </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="product-section">
    <img class="img-reposnive" src="../img/product/tv_cabinet/1.png">
    <h5> Cabinet_2 </h5>
    <div class="details">
     <p> PRICE : 19000 Yen </p>
     <p> Size : 162 X 72 X 80 cm </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="product-section">
    <img class="img-reposnive" src="../img/product/tv_cabinet/1.png">
    <h5> Cabinet_3 </h5>
    <div class="details">
     <p> PRICE : 19000 Yen </p>
     <p> Size : 162 X 72 X 80 cm </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="product-section">
    <img class="img-reposnive" src="../img/product/tv_cabinet/1.png">
    <h5> Cabinet_4 </h5>
    <div class="details">
     <p> PRICE : 19000 Yen </p>
     <p> Size : 162 X 72 X 80 cm </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
   <div class="product-section">
    <img class="img-reposnive" src="../img/product/tv_cabinet/1.png">
    <h5> Cabinet_5 </h5>
    <div class="details">
     <p> PRICE : 19000 Yen </p>
     <p> Size : 162 X 72 X 80 cm </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```